# Reg Ex for a negative lookaround or negative assertion for an underscore needed

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, scrapy

I've got URL patterns that always start with one of 3 words behind the toplevel url:

```
word1
word2
word3
```

Then there could be anything in several subdirectories (up to 4 levels deep) but ALWAYS:
`lowercaseword` or `lowercaseword-lowercaseword`

Now I'm searching for a reg ex which would match exactly this but not a subdirectory starting with an underscore:
`_lowercaseword`

So my URLs are:

```
example.com/word1/lowercaseword/lowercaseword/?parameters
example.com/word2/lowercaseword/
example.com/word3/lowercaseword/lowercaseword/lowercaseword/
example.com/word2/lowercaseword/lowercaseword/_lowercaseword/
```

and I'm searching for a reg ex that **matches the first three**.

I can't figure out the negative lookaround (if that's what is needed).
Any ideas?

These are my expressions, but they're not working:

```
\/(word1|word2|word3)\/((?!\_)[a-z]+(\-[a-z]+)?\/){0,4}
\/(word1|word2|word3)\/([!\_a-z]+(\-[a-z]+)?\/){0,4}
```

Comment: Try `^[^/]+/(word1|word2|word3)(?:/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?){0,4}/?(?:\?.*)?$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W6vuzs/2)

Comment: I see how a regex would be the first thought, but considering complexity, readability and maintainability of the code, I think in this specific case you'd be better off with a different approach. Specifically, you can use `urllib.parse` to get the URL parameters and see if they start with `_` when you need it. This would also allow to more easily keep a list of `word`s that you want to match.

Comment: @ChatterOne would be my fav solution as well but the regex are a requirement inside my code structure for a scrapy spider. I just haven't mentioned scrapy since I thought it wouldn't matter for this question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, that seems to be working indeed.
If you add this into an answer, I'll accept it as the one. :)

Comment: @Chris Posted with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[^/]+/(word1|word2|word3)(?:/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?){0,4}/?(?:\?.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W6vuzs/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `/` - a slash
- `(word1|word2|word3)` - any of the words
- `(?:/[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?){0,4}` - zero to four repetitions of `/`, 1+ lowercase ASCII 
  letters and then an optional sequence of `-` and 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `(?:\?.*)?` - an optional sequence of `?` and then any 0+ chars up to the...
- `$` - end of string.